# Apache Camel split runs in parallell with ThreadPool, why?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, split, apache-camel, threadpool

I have a camelRoute that should use a threadPool in a split to do parallell work. My problem is that i **always end up with one thread too much because the split will run one thread and the threadpool the specified amount of threads.** I would like the threadpool to cap the amount of threads.

Anyone can see why this happens? Route and camel-context below... (other values in code, like from and id etc, but cant show that here...)

```
from(FROM_ENDPOINT)
    .routeId(ID)
    .split(body(), new GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy())
    .executorServiceRef("ThreadPool")
    .bean(bean, "beanMethod")
    .end()
    .bean(bean)
    .multicast()
    .to(TO_ENDPOINT);
```

The ThreadPool is configured like so in my camel-context.xml:

```
<camel:camelContext id="application-context" useMDCLogging="true" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="ref:props"/>
    <routeBuilder ref="refToRoute"/>
    <threadPoolProfile id="ThreadPool" maxPoolSize="2"
                       maxQueueSize="-1" poolSize="2"/>
</camel:camelContext>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The splitter needs one background thread to orchestrate the parallel work. So you have the threads from the thread pool + one extra thread with the name `Splitter-AggregateTask`.

So if you want a total max of 10, then set the thread pool size to be 9, so you have room for that 1 background thread also.

Comment: Thank you, good to know why I have an extra thread. I have thought of setting the threadpool value to one less but what if I would like to run with 1 thread? In test there would be beneficial to use only one thread as the work we are doing in the threadpool logs values that we need to see in order and parallell flow will make this very hard to follow. The only solution i have now is to remove the threadpool from the route.

Comment: For 1 thread then do not use a thread pool, then its all sequential and in that same order.

Comment: Yes I understand that but I would like to have a threadpool in production but not in test due to debugging. I don't want two codebases for test/prod but i would just like to configure the threadpool to use 1 thread in test and several in production. But this may be impossible?

Comment: Sure use property placeholders so you can have different propreties file for test vs production

Comment: But that does not help me. The executor service is in the route and even though i bring down threads to 1 or 0 in my property file there will always be 2 threads. One for the split and one for executor service. I have to completely remove ".executorServiceRef("ThreadPool")" from the code (and rebuild) if i want 1 thread.

Comment: Its bad to have test being too different than production. So if you use thread pools in production, then use it for testing also. Or look at using advice-with for testing where you can replace/remove/change your routes as you want.